# Create a deck of playing cards & draw a hand of cards

Tags: python, python-3.x, playing-cards

I built a very [basic blackjack program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/239990/100620) a couple of weeks ago, but I've learned a lot since then, and would like some input on a couple of basic functions for card games: a build_deck function and a draw_hand function.

It seems pretty efficient use of code (at least compared to my previous attempt) but I'm sure there are some ways I can improve on it.

```
import random

def build_deck():
# The deck is a list of tuples, with each tuple representing a card.
# Each card has a name, face, suit, and value.
    deck = []
    value = 0
    face = ''
    for value in range(13):
        value += 1
        suit_list = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
        for suit in suit_list:
            if value == 1:
                face = 'Ace'
            elif value == 11:
                face = 'Jack'
            elif value == 12:
                face = 'Queen'
            elif value == 13:
                face = 'King'
            else:
                face = str(value)
            name = 'the %s of %s' % (face, suit)
            # The deck is shuffled only once, when the deck is first built.
            random.shuffle(deck)
            deck.append((name, face, suit, value))
    return deck

def draw_hand(hand_size):
    # The player receives a card into their hand while the same card is removed from the deck.
    player_hand = []
    for draw in range(int(hand_size)):
        selected_card = (random.choice(deck))
        print('You drew %s.' % (selected_card[0]))
        player_hand.append(selected_card)
        deck.remove(selected_card)
    return player_hand

deck = build_deck()
player_hand= draw_hand(input('How many cards do you want to draw? There are %s cards in the deck.' % (str(len(deck)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Shuffling the Deck

Your comment `# The deck is shuffled only once, when the deck is first built` is wrong.  You are shuffling the deck 52 times; once after before each card is added:

```
    deck = []
    for value in range(13):
        suit_list = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
        for suit in suit_list:
            ...
            random.shuffle(deck) # This line is executed 13 * 4 times!
            deck.append((name, face, suit, value))
    return deck
```

Additionally, you are grabbing cards from a random location in the middle of the deck, so it doesn't matter if you shuffled the deck or not:

```
        selected_card = (random.choice(deck))
        ...
        deck.remove(selected_card)
```

You should build the complete deck, and then shuffle it once:

```
    deck = []
    for value in range(13):
        suit_list = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
        for suit in suit_list:
            ...
            deck.append((name, face, suit, value))

    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck
```

And then, deal from the top of the deck:

```
        selected_card = deck.pop(0)
```

## Suits

```
    for value in range(13):
        value += 1
        suit_list = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
        for suit in suit_list:
```

The `suit_list` doesn't change.  It doesn't need to be recreated for each of the 13 card ranks.  You should move it out of the inner loop.

There it is still a local variable.  Code which wants to use your deck of cards might want/need to know the what all the suits in your deck are.  Is it a normal playing card deck, or a deck of Tarot cards?  Is the spade suit represented as "Spades", "SPADES", "S", "♠" or "♤"?

An `enum` would be a better entity to use as a card suit:

```
from enum import Enum

Suit = Enum('Suit', 'Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades')
```

Then a program could safely refer to the spade suit as `Suit.Spades`, and iinstead of:

```
        suit_list = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
        for suit in suit_list:
```

You'd simply iterate over the `Suit` enum:

```
        for suit in Suit:
```

You can still use `suit.name` to get a nice string for the `suit`.

## range(start, end, step)

Instead of writing:

```
    for value in range(13):
        value += 1
        ...
```

use the fact that a range can start at any value, so you don't need to add 1 to the card's rank at each iteration; just iterate over a different range:

```
    for value in range(1, 13+1):
        ...
```

## Each tuple represents a card ...

Ok ... lemme think.  The `card[0]` is the card's rank, and `card[1]` is the card's suit?  Or do have have that backwards ; `card[0]` is the suit and `card[1]` is the rank?

With a tuple, it is easy to forget which member is stored in which field.  It is way easier to use a named tuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Card = nametuple('Card', 'name, face, suit, value')
```

Then we wouldn't have to remember; `card.rank` is the the card's rank, and `card.suit` is the card's suit.

The only downside is ... uhh ... no, sorry, there are no downsides.  A `namedtuple` is just as efficient time and space wise.  You'd create the cards like this:

```
        deck.append(Card(name, face, suit, value))
```

And instead of

```
    print('You drew %s.' % (selected_card[0]))
```

you'd write:

```
    print('You drew %s.' % selected_card.name)
```

## Formatting

The inner parenthesis are unnecessary here:

```
    print('You drew %s.' % (selected_card[0]))
```

They take the value "the Ace of Spaces", and ... return that string unaltered.  So we end up with the expression `str % str`, and since the first string contains only one `%s` code, the argument is directly used.

if you had used `(selected_card[0], )`, that would have constructed a tuple of 1 values, a string, which could also be applied to that format string.  Without the trailing comma, you don't have a tuple.

It is easier to use f-strings.  There, the format arguments are placed directly in the format codes, instead of at the end where they have to be match up by positions.  Instead of:

```
            name = 'the %s of %s' % (face, suit)
```

you could write:

```
            name = f'the {face} of {suit}'
```

which is slightly more compact, and much easier to tell where the values are going in the resulting string.

## Hand size

```
def draw_hand(hand_size):
    player_hand = []
    for draw in range(int(hand_size)):
```

Wait ... what is that `int(...)` doing there?  What are you expecting to pass to `draw_hand`, if not an integer?  Why would you allow it to be a string?

It should be the caller's responsibility for any string to integer conversions.  This function should only expect an integer for `hand_size`.

## Improved code

Using `NamedTuple` instead of `namedtuple`, a `Rank` enumeration, and reducing `Card` to just a tuple of `rank` and `suit`, with `str(card)` corresponding to the card's name, and `card.rank.value` for the card's value ... along with some other structural modifications:

```
from random import shuffle
from enum import Enum
from typing import NamedTuple, List
from itertools import product

Suit = Enum('Suit', 'Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades')
Rank = Enum('Rank', 'Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King')

class Card(NamedTuple):
    rank: Rank
    suit: Suit

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.rank.name} of {self.suit.name}"

def build_deck() -> List[Card]:
    deck = [Card(rank, suit) for rank, suit in product(Rank, Suit)]
    shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def draw_hand(hand_size: int) -> List[Card]:
    return [deck.pop(0) for _ in range(hand_size)]

def print_hand(hand: List[Card]) -> None:
    print("You drew:", ", ".join(str(card) for card in hand))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    deck = build_deck()
    n = int(input(f"How many cards? There are {len(deck)} cards in the deck: "))
    hand = draw_hand(n)
    print_hand(hand)
```

Result:

> How many cards? There are 52 cards in the deck: 5
>   You drew: 2 of Hearts, 9 of Clubs, 5 of Hearts, 7 of Hearts, Queen of Clubs

Comment: Thanks for providing the enum and namedtuple code, I haven't seen those before and will read up on them.

As far as the int for hand size, I had thought that input() always returned a string, but I might have been wrong in that regard.

Comment: `input()` does return a string, which is why I have `int(input))`.  The point is `draw_hand()` shouldn’t handle `hand_size` given as a string.  It should expect an integer.

Comment: Using an `IntEnum` or `OrderedEnum`, enables card ranks to be compared.  Because the Rank Enum uses numbers for member names, the ranks should be  accessed using Rank['4'] or Rank['Queen'].  While `Rank.Queen` works, `Rank.4` will give a syntax error.

Comment: @RootTwo If you have a number, and need the corresponding card `Rank`, you should use `Rank(4)`, not `Rank['4']`, to get the Rack enum who's value is 4.  Ordering cards by rank was not important in the OP's previous post (Blackjack), so I stopped before introducing `OrderedEnum`.  It also opens a can or worms about whether ace's should be high or low, and perhaps ordering should be imposed by the game played with the cards and not by the cards themselves.